# Overshoot more than 100%

Tags: control

I am modeling a line sensor car, I like to find out the transfer function of the car under an unit step input for a steady speed so that the system dynamics stay the same for the constant speed.

From the sampling position of the car when apply unit step input, I find an overshooting of more than 100% in the car, which is overshooting 156%.

From there, when I apply the formula of Mp = exp(- damp * pi / (sqrt(1 - sq(damp))), i get a nice damping ratio which is 0.14.

However, when i plot the graph in the Matlab, the overshoot is shown is only 64% as with that value, the damping ratio is also 0.14.

How do u plot the diagram with the exact 156% overshooting?

Comment: Are you asking why Matlab gives 64% overshoot and theoretical analysis gives 56% overshoot?

Comment: From the experiment, the analysis shows 156% overshooting, from the formula i provide above, it can find out the damping ratio, which is 0.14. However, when i plot the graph in Matlab, it shows a graph with a 64% overshooting. I can understand that because in the formula calculation, when damping ratio is 0.14, it has two possible answer, one is 64% overshooting and another one is 156% overshooting. But how can i plot a graph with that 156% overshooting instead of 64% overshooting?

Comment: See answer, below.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean peak overshoot or percentage overshoot? They are not the same.

Peak overshoot (expressed in percent) is: \$\frac{peak\:value}{final\:value}\small \: .\:100\$%

Percentage overshoot is: \$\frac{peak\:value\:-\:final\:value}{final\:value}\:.\:\small 100\$%

e.g. for a unit step input, a final value of unity, and a peak value of 1.6, the percentage overshoot is 60% and the peak overshoot is 160%.

Comment: Percentage overshoot. E.g. for a unit step input, a final value of unity, 1.0, and a peak value of 2.6, the percentage overshooting is 160%. Does this case exist? I am modeling a line sensor car track.

Comment: Not for a 2nd order system - maximum would be 100% overshoot, and that would be an oscillator.